# How to turn off creating snapshots in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

```
./target/debug/cnosdb --version
cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 57248a5c8b2bf7669bbf9ebb33a12c1bd51b19cc
```

./target/debug/cnosdb run  --config config_file.toml -M singleton

Running cnosdb in single instance mode still generates many snapshot files,
which should be used in cluster mode; How to turn off during single instance runtime.